# storing class instance with template on std::vector

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class, that I created to format some strings based in some conditions...

```
template <class PropObject, class PropType, PropType PropObject::* Prop>
class FlatFileStructure
{
private:
    size_t _startPosition;
    size_t _size;
    int _fieldStyle;

public:
    FlatFileStructure(size_t posicaoInicial, size_t tamanho, TipoDoCampo tipoDoCampo)
        : _startPosition(posicaoInicial),
        _size(tamanho),
        _fieldStyle(tipoDoCampo)
    {}


    size_t getPosicaoInicial() { return _startPosition; }
    size_t getTamanho() { return _size; }

    std::string getConteudoFormatado(const std::string& tmpConteudo)
    {
        PropObject& po = static_cast<PropObject&>(o);
        PropType& t = po.*Prop;

        std::string conteudo = t;

        if (_tipoDoCampo == TipoDoCampo::ALFANUMERICO)
        {
            if (conteudo.size() > _tamanho)
                conteudo = util::truncate(conteudo, _tamanho);

            conteudo = util::pad_right(conteudo, _tamanho, ' ');
        }

        else if (_tipoDoCampo == TipoDoCampo::NUMERICO || _tipoDoCampo == TipoDoCampo::NUMERICO_SEQUENCIAL)
        {
            if (conteudo.size() > _tamanho)
                conteudo = util::truncate_numeric(conteudo, _tamanho);

            conteudo = util::pad_left(conteudo, _tamanho, '0');
        }

        else if (_tipoDoCampo == TipoDoCampo::DATA)
        {
            if (conteudo.empty())
                conteudo = dragonfly::DateTimeHelper::hoje("%d%m%y");
            else
                conteudo = dragonfly::DateTimeHelper::formataData_de_para(conteudo, "%d.%m.%Y", "%d%m%y");
        }

        return conteudo;
    }
};
```

To use this class, I have this code:

```
_descricaoDosCampos = new std::vector<????????>();
_descricaoDosCampos->push_back(new FlatFileStructure<Tipo0, std::string, &Tipo0::tipoRegistro>(0, 1, TipoDoCampo::NUMERICO, "0"));
_descricaoDosCampos->push_back(new FlatFileStructure<Tipo0, std::string, &Tipo0::sequencialRegistro>(394, 6, TipoDoCampo::NUMERICO_SEQUENCIAL, "000001"));
```

How I can do too store the class instance on std::vector, that I can interact over the vector too ( I tried to create a 'object' class, that the FlatFileStructure class inherited, but, I'm not able to cast from "Object" to 'FlatFileStructure<X,Y,T>'

Comment: `std::any` is one option, a non-templated base class and storing `unique_ptr`s to them is another option.

Comment: Whenever you see `new std::vector` you should ask yourself if a pointer is really the right tool for the job. Because it rarely is. It's rare that you would want a`std::vector<T>*` member instead of `std::vector<T>`. And in those cases, you almost certainly want `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>` instead.

Comment: Consider using polymorphism here. You can place the common template-agnostic interface of your type in a base type and derive from that base type in your actual template class. It seems like non of your interface depends on the template arguments, so this may entirely solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conisder the public interface only (and rename the template paramters, it is advisable to use different naming convention than for "normal" types):

```
template <class T, class U, U T::* Prop>
class FlatFileStructure
{
public:
    FlatFileStructure(size_t posicaoInicial, size_t tamanho, TipoDoCampo tipoDoCampo);
    size_t getPosicaoInicial();
    size_t getTamanho();
    std::string getConteudoFormatado(const std::string& tmpConteudo);
};
```

Nothing of the interface depends on the template parameter. You can move the interface to a non-template base class:

```
struct base {
public:
    base(size_t posicaoInicial, size_t tamanho, TipoDoCampo tipoDoCampo);       
    virtual size_t getPosicaoInicial();
    virtual size_t getTamanho();
    virtual std::string getConteudoFormatado(const std::string& tmpConteudo);
    virtual ~base() = default;
};
```

And use a vector of shared pointers to that base class:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>>
```

The concrete classes can be templated:

```
template <class T, class U, U T::* Prop>
class FlatFileStructure : public base {

    std::string getConteudoFormatado(const std::string& tmpConteudo) override {
        // do any T/U specific stuff here
     }
};
```

> ... but, I'm not able to cast from "Object" to 'FlatFileStructure<X,Y,T>'

If you have to cast, then there is something wrong with your design. Assuming you didn't leave out details, the public interface of `FlatFileStructure<A,C,D>` is exactly the same for any `A,B,C` and there should never be the need to cast.

PS: You certainly do not want `new std::vector`. A `std::vector` already does manage its memory for you, and thats one main reason to use it.

Comment: The "getConteudoFormatado" uses the template parameters

Comment: @CarlosRodrigues sorry there were some mistakes in the code (somehow forgot about virtual). Only internals of `getConteudoFormatado` use the template parameters, the implementation is in the derived classes